# Getting GaxiosError: request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT to generate oauth2 accesstoken for FCM

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, google-oauth, google-auth-library

I have created an nodejs api to generate oauth2 accessToken using google-auth-library for FCM HTTP V1 API.

This api generates an oauth2 accessToken which will then be used by my react app to make a request to FCM HTTP V1 API.

The api code works fine on my local machine gives the excepted output. But when this code is deployed on server I am facing timeout issue for https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token this endpoint.

Provide me solution on how can I solve this ....what is the reason for this issue?

Below is my code for generating oauth2 access token:

```
module.exports.generateToken = async function (transactionId) { 
try 
{ 
    const SCOPES = [config.MESSAGING_SCOPE]; 
    const currentTimeZone = new Date(Date.now()); 
    currentTimeZone.setHours( currentTimeZone.getHours() + config.AccessTokenExpiryTime );
    const auth = new GoogleAuth({
      credentials: {
        client_email: config.client_email,
        private_key: config.private_key,
      },
      scopes: SCOPES,
    });


    const client = await auth.getClient();
    const accessToken = await client.getAccessToken();
    globalaccessToken = accessToken.token;
    tokenExpiry = currentTimeZone;

    loggerDetail.debug(transactionId + " AccessToken Retrieved Successfully ");

    return {
      accessTokenValue: globalaccessToken,
      tokenExpiration: tokenExpiry,
    };
}catch (error) { 
   loggerDetail.debug( transactionId + " Failed to retrieve access token:  " + error.message );
} 
};
```